# Formal definition of line integral along reversible and irreversible path

Tags: calculus, physics, mathematical-physics, differential-forms, line-integrals

In thermodynamics work can be done by moving by reversible or irreversible path. Physical definition of reversible and irreversible process is weary common in thermodynamics textbooks. What does it mean mathematically? How to formalize it?
Work is line integral of differential form.
$$W=\int_{L} P(x, y, z) dx+Q(x, y, z) dy+R(x, y, z) dz$$ 
where L is equation of curve.
If work is function of p and V, does it mean that there are curves on p-V plane that have property of being reversible or irreversible path?

Comment: This is a (chemical/physical) notion from thermodynamics — referring to a thermodynamic *process* as reversible or irreversible. This is not really a mathematical notion, to the best of my recollection. The distinction between state and non-state variables and the distinction between exact and inexact differentials are, on the other hand, mathematical notions.

Answer (score 0):

Your concept of $L$ is faulty.

Equations like $f(x,y,z)=0$ do not define curves, instead they generally define surfaces. For example, $x+y+z=1$ is a flat plane.

Instead, when defining a curve along which to take a path integral, one uses a curve $L$ that is defined parametrically, like this: 
$$L(t) = (f(t),g(t),h(t)) \quad\text{for some interval $a \le t \le b$}
$$
Then the work integral becomes
$$W =\int_{L} P(x, y, z) \, dx+Q(x, y, z) \, dy+R(x, y, z)\, dz$$
$$ = \int_a^b \left(P(f(t),g(t),h(z)) \frac{df}{dt} + Q(f(t),g(t),h(t)) \frac{dg}{dt} + R(f(t),g(t),h(t)) \frac{dh}{dt}\right) dt
$$
This has nothing to do with whether the path $L$ is reversible or irreversible: *this equation* is the definition of work done by moving a particle along the path $L$, through the force field given by $P$, $Q$ and $R$.

Comment: Thank you for showing my mistake. I am interested what does $$\int_{L,irreversible} $$ means. I am not interested in how to solve line integrals.

Comment: As said, I don't know what you mean by that. That is not a notation with which I am familiar. You asked how to formalize work mathematically, and that is the answer that I gave. To repeat, that line integral **is** the formal mathematical definition of work, no matter what other properties that path may have (whether that path is reversible, or irreversible, or round, or crooked, or anything else).

Comment: In thermodynamics work can be done reversible and irreversible way. It is weary important in treatise of second law of thermodynamics. This notation is main point of my question.